# Writing training model for CNN

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, training-data, chainer

I am writing the training code for [TwoStream-IQA](https://github.com/qingsenyangit/Two-stream_IQA) which is a two-stream convolutional neural network. This model predicts the quality score for the patches being assessed through two streams of the network. In the training below, I have used test dataset provided in the GitHub link above.

The training code is as below:

```
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import argparse

import chainer

chainer.global_config.train=True

from chainer import cuda
from chainer import serializers
from chainer import optimizers
from chainer import iterators
from chainer import training 
from chainer.training import extensions
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches

from model import Model

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='train.py')
parser.add_argument('--model', '-m', default='', 
                    help='path to the trained model')
parser.add_argument('--gpu', '-g', default=0, type=int, help='GPU ID')

args = parser.parse_args()


model = Model()

cuda.cudnn_enabled = True
cuda.check_cuda_available()
xp = cuda.cupy
model.to_gpu()

## prepare training data 
test_label_path = 'data_list/test.txt'
test_img_path = 'data/live/'
test_Graimg_path = 'data/live_grad/'
save_model_path = '/models/nr_sana_2stream.model'

patches_per_img = 256
patchSize = 32

print('-------------Load data-------------')
final_train_set = []
with open(test_label_path, 'rt') as f:
    for l in f:
        line, la = l.strip().split()  # for debug

        tic = time.time()
        full_path = os.path.join(test_img_path, line)
        Grafull_path = os.path.join(test_Graimg_path, line)

        inputImage = Image.open(full_path)
        Graf = Image.open(Grafull_path)
        img = np.asarray(inputImage, dtype=np.float32)
        Gra = np.asarray(Graf, dtype=np.float32)
        img = img.transpose(2, 0, 1)
        Gra = Gra.transpose(2, 0, 1)

        img1 = np.zeros((1, 3, Gra.shape[1], Gra.shape[2]))
        img1[0, :, :, :] = img
        Gra1 = np.zeros((1, 3, Gra.shape[1], Gra.shape[2]))
        Gra1[0, :, :, :] = Gra

        patches = extract_patches(img, (3, patchSize, patchSize), patchSize)
        Grapatches = extract_patches(Gra, (3, patchSize, patchSize), patchSize)

        X = patches.reshape((-1, 3, patchSize, patchSize))
        GraX = Grapatches.reshape((-1, 3, patchSize, patchSize))

        temp_slice1 = [X[int(float(index))] for index in range(256)]
        temp_slice2 = [GraX[int(float(index))] for index in range(256)]
        ##############################################  
        for j in range(len(temp_slice1)):
            temp_slice1[j] = xp.array(temp_slice1[j].astype(np.float32))
            temp_slice2[j] = xp.array(temp_slice2[j].astype(np.float32))

            final_train_set.append((
                np.asarray((temp_slice1[j], temp_slice2[j])).astype(np.float32),
                int(la)
                ))      
        ##############################################  
print('--------------Done!----------------')

print('--------------Iterator!----------------')    
train_iter = iterators.SerialIterator(final_train_set, batch_size=4)
optimizer = optimizers.Adam()
optimizer.use_cleargrads()
optimizer.setup(model)

updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, device=0)

print('--------------Trainer!----------------') 
trainer = training.Trainer(updater, (50, 'epoch'), out='result')

trainer.extend(extensions.LogReport())

trainer.extend(extensions.PrintReport(['epoch', 'iteration', 'main/loss', 'elapsed_time']))

print('--------------Running trainer!----------------') 
trainer.run()
```

But the code is producing error on line `trainer.run()` as:

```
-------------Load data-------------
--------------Done!----------------
--------------Iterator!----------------
--------------Trainer!----------------
--------------Running trainer!----------------
Exception in main training loop: Unsupported dtype object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 316, in run
    update()
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 154, in update_core
    in_arrays = self.converter(batch, self.device)
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 149, in concat_examples
    return to_device(device, _concat_arrays(batch, padding))
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 37, in to_device
    return cuda.to_gpu(x, device)
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 285, in to_gpu
    return _array_to_gpu(array, device_, stream)
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 333, in _array_to_gpu
    return cupy.asarray(array)
  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/creation/from_data.py", line 60, in asarray
    return core.array(a, dtype, False)
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2049, in cupy.core.core.array
  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2083, in cupy.core.core.array
Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-69-12b84b41c6b9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/mnt/nas/sanaalamgeer/Projects/1/MyOwnChainer/Two-stream_IQA-master/train.py', wdir='/mnt/nas/sanaalamgeer/Projects/1/MyOwnChainer/Two-stream_IQA-master')

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/mnt/nas/sanaalamgeer/Projects/1/MyOwnChainer/Two-stream_IQA-master/train.py", line 129, in <module>
    trainer.run()

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 330, in run
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/trainer.py", line 316, in run
    update()

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 149, in update
    self.update_core()

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/training/updaters/standard_updater.py", line 154, in update_core
    in_arrays = self.converter(batch, self.device)

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 149, in concat_examples
    return to_device(device, _concat_arrays(batch, padding))

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/dataset/convert.py", line 37, in to_device
    return cuda.to_gpu(x, device)

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 285, in to_gpu
    return _array_to_gpu(array, device_, stream)

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chainer/backends/cuda.py", line 333, in _array_to_gpu
    return cupy.asarray(array)

  File "/home/sanaalamgeer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cupy/creation/from_data.py", line 60, in asarray
    return core.array(a, dtype, False)

  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2049, in cupy.core.core.array

  File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 2083, in cupy.core.core.array

ValueError: Unsupported dtype object
```

Maybe thats's because I am arraging `training data` wrong because the model takes training parameters as:

```
length = x_data.shape[0]
x1 = Variable(x_data[0:length:2])
x2 = Variable(x_data[1:length:2])
```

and `y_data` as:

```
t = xp.repeat(y_data[0:length:2], 1)
```

The variable `final_train_set` prepapres dataset of a `tuple (Numpy Array, 66)` where every `Numpy Array` has dimensions `(2, 3, 32, 32)` which carries two types patches `(3, 32, 32)`.

I have used dataset from the github link provided above.
I am a newbie in Chainer,Please help!!

Comment: I guess the input shape is different. batch size dimension is not necessary when creating dataset. Can you try: 
        `X = patches.reshape((-1, 3, patchSize, patchSize))` → `X = patches.reshape((3, patchSize, patchSize))` and 
        `GraX = Grapatches.reshape((-1, 3, patchSize, patchSize))` → `GraX = Grapatches.reshape((3, patchSize, patchSize))`

Comment: It generates another `ValueError` which says: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1013760 into shape (3,32,32)`

Comment: `dtype` refers to the data type, it sounds like you are passing a wrong type argument somewhere. Can you provide the stack trace? Where is this error being raised from?

Comment: @nuric I have put detailed error (with outputs from PRINT() statements).

Comment: Are you OK with using Keras?

Comment: Do you want it for image recognition?

Comment: @Xilpex No, that's for quality assessment of images.

Comment: @Xilpex Do you know any two-stream model written in Keras for quality assessment?

Comment: Is it fine by you to get a github repo to study?

Comment: @Xilpex: yes, I have my GitHub account already.

Answer (score 1):

In very short, you inappropriately called `numpy.asarray`: `numpy.asarray` does not concatenate two `cupy.ndarray`s, while it concatenates two `numpy.ndarray`s.

Your code in brief:

```
import numpy, cupy

final_train_set = []

N_PATCH_PER_IMAGE = 8

for i in range(10):
    label = 0

    temp_slice_1 = [numpy.zeros((3, 3)) for j in range(N_PATCH_PER_IMAGE)]
    temp_slice_2 = [numpy.zeros((3, 3)) for j in range(N_PATCH_PER_IMAGE)]

    for j in range(N_PATCH_PER_IMAGE):
        temp_slice_1[j] = cupy.array(temp_slice_1[j])
        temp_slice_2[j] = cupy.array(temp_slice_2[j])
        final_train_set.append(
            [
                # attempting to concatenate two cupy arrays by numpy.asarray 
                numpy.asarray([temp_slice_1[j], temp_slice_2[j]]),
                label
            ]
        )
```

The bug

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

print("two numpy arrays")
print(np.asarray([np.zeros(shape=(1,)), np.zeros(shape=(1,))]))
print(np.asarray([np.zeros(shape=(1,)), np.zeros(shape=(1,))]).dtype)

print()

print("two cupy arrays")
print(np.asarray([cp.zeros(shape=(1,)), cp.zeros(shape=(1,))]))
print(np.asarray([cp.zeros(shape=(1,)), cp.zeros(shape=(1,))]).dtype)
```

```
two numpy arrays
[[0.]
 [0.]]
float64

two cupy arrays
[[array(0.)]
 [array(0.)]]
object
```

Solution: comment out two lines

```
import numpy  # not import cupy here

for i in range(10):
    label = 0

    temp_slice_1 = [numpy.zeros((3, 3)) for j in range(N_PATCH_PER_IMAGE)]
    temp_slice_2 = [numpy.zeros((3, 3)) for j in range(N_PATCH_PER_IMAGE)]

    for j in range(N_PATCH_PER_IMAGE):
        # temp_slice_1[j] = cupy.array(temp_slice_1[j]) <- comment out!
        # temp_slice_2[j] = cupy.array(temp_slice_2[j]) <- comment out!
        final_train_set.append(
            [
                # concatenate two numpy arrays: usually cupy should not be used in dataset
                numpy.asarray([temp_slice_1[j], temp_slice_2[j]]),
                label
            ]
        )
```

---

Footnote

1. In the code you presented, `xp` is not specified, so you could not get answer from anyone. Please post WHOLE BODY of your code including the model if you were not able to separate the problem.
2. I guess you *might* not able to run the training code for another reason. In this code, the data is first brought to the main memory in the construction of `final_train_set`. But if the number of images is huge, the main memory would run out and `MemoryError` would be raised. (In other words, if the number of image is small and your memory is large enough, the error would not be happen) 
   In that case, the following references ([Chainer at glance](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/glance.html) and [Dataset Abstraction](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/datasets.html)) would help.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I have added line `xp = cuda.cupy`.

Comment: Error is still there: `ValueError: Unsupported dtype object`.

Comment: What's `y_data`? Could you try to remove all xp from your code? Does it work?

Comment: `y_data` is for labels (target values). `xp` was used only for `temp_slices` values, nowhere else, removing it all doesn't work either.

Comment: I looked into the original Two-Stream IQA, but the code does not make sense. For example, the model defines `conv2`, `conv4`, `conv6`, `conv8`, `conv10` which are never used. I can show you the code to train, but I wonder you trust this code?

Comment: OK, I withdraw from this issue, I'm sorry but I cannot go further from the original code, and I'm reluctant to re-implement the original code to suit for the training.

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry to know that. As far as my trust in that model is concerned, I had to, because they have published a paper with this model with good correlations. :(

Answer (score -1):

**DISCLAIMER: None of this code is written by me**

I found [this](https://github.com/jiawenzhou0627/image-quality-assessment-python/blob/master/brisque_features.py) Github repository using OpenCV, Scipy and a few other module for the quality assessment. Here is the code:

```
# Python code for BRISQUE model
# Original paper title: No-Reference Image Quality Assessment in the Spatial Domain
# Link: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6272356/
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import math

def get_gaussian_filter():
    [m,n] = [(ss - 1.0) / 2.0 for ss in (shape,shape)]
    [y,x] = np.ogrid[-m:m+1,-n:n+1]
    window = np.exp( -(x*x + y*y) / (2.0*sigma*sigma) )
    window[window < np.finfo(window.dtype).eps*window.max() ] = 0
    sum_window = window.sum()
    if sum_window != 0:
        window = np.divide(window, sum_window)
    return window

def lmom(X):
    (rows, cols)  = X.shape
    if cols == 1:
        X = X.reshape(1,rows)
    n = rows
    X.sort()    
    b = np.zeros(3)    
    b0 = X.mean()    
    for r in range(1,4):        
        Num = np.prod(np.tile(np.arange(r+1,n+1), (r,1))-np.tile(np.arange(1,r+1).reshape(r,1),(1,n-r)),0)        
        Num = Num.astype(np.float)                
        Den = np.prod(np.tile(n, (1, r)) - np.arange(1,r+1), 1)        
        b[r-1] = 1.0/n * sum(Num/Den * X[0,r:])
    L = np.zeros(4)
    L[0] = b0
    L[1] = 2*b[0] - b0
    L[2] = 6*b[1] - 6*b[0] + b0
    L[3] = 20*b[2] - 30*b[1] + 12*b[0] - b0
    return L

def compute_features(im):
    im = im.astype(np.float)
    window = get_gaussian_filter()
    scalenum = 2
    feat = []
    for itr_scale in range(scalenum):
        mu = cv2.filter2D(im, cv2.CV_64F, window, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
        mu_sq = mu * mu
        sigma = np.sqrt(abs(cv2.filter2D(im*im, cv2.CV_64F, window, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT) - mu_sq))        
        structdis = (im-mu)/(sigma+1)
        structdis_col_vector = np.reshape(structdis.transpose(), (structdis.size,1))
        L = lmom(structdis.reshape(structdis.size,1))
        feat = np.append(feat,[L[1], L[3]])
        shifts = [[0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [-1,1]]
        for itr_shift in shifts:
            shifted_structdis = np.roll(structdis, itr_shift[0], axis=0)
            shifted_structdis = np.roll(shifted_structdis, itr_shift[1], axis=1)

            shifted_structdis_col_vector = np.reshape(shifted_structdis.T, (shifted_structdis.size,1))
            pair = structdis_col_vector * shifted_structdis_col_vector
            L = lmom(pair.reshape(pair.size,1))
            feat = np.append(feat, L)
        im = cv2.resize(im, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return feat


im = ndimage.imread('example.bmp', flatten=True)
feat = compute_features(im)
print feat
```

Comment: Thank you for this post but I know BRISQUE which is a conventional algorithm. I want to assess the quality by using or modifying a two-stream CNN network. I am more concerned about CNN with 2-streams.